# CSS :hover issue displaying elements and background images

Tags: hover

I'm having an issue getting the hover to work on my project. I used this code in a different project and worked fine (although I did not use the background image in that project). Ive tried modifying the hover to access ID and Class on separate blocks, no luck. Thanks for taking a look!

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="divTableRow">
 <a href="#">
   <div class="divTableCell in-news">
     <h3>In the News</h3>
     <div class="hvr">
       <p>Read about the buzz viveve is creating</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </a>
 <a href="#">
   <div class="divTableCell" id="investor">
     <h3>Investor News</h3><div class="hvr">
       <p>Read about Viveve's financials</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.in-news {
    background-color: #C4D600;
}

.in-news:hover {
  background-color: none;
  background-image: url(Images\InTheNews.png);
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top 20px center;
}

#investor {
    background-color: #8999BA;
}

#investor:hover {
    background-color: none;
    background-image: url(images\InvestorNews.png);
    background-size: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top 20px center;
}

.divTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 3px;
}

.hvr {
  display: none;
}

.hvr:hover {
  display:inline;
}
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing quotes around the images URL. So it should be:

`background-image: url("images\InvestorNews.png");`

instead of:

`background-image: url(images\InvestorNews.png);`

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/wedgess/pen/YOpBoq

Comment: I knew it had to be small syntax! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us. Can you please accept as answer if it fixed your issue. Thanks